# How to find a model in cakePHP (I can't find)?

Tags: cakephp, model

I have taken over a project for cakePHP, I am new and I find it not easy, Magento should be difficult but I find cakePHP more difficult, but maybe I have not reach the moment I know it ...

I have the next model (for table postcodes):

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Postcode' => array(
        'className' => 'Postcode',
        'foreignKey' => 'postcode_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
```

Everything works, but with the tool AgentRansack I can't find the model Postcode. And besides the name of the table is postcodes, I can't even find a relation for Postcode and postcodes.

How can such a model setup in a different way than with a class Postcode.php ?

Comment: Things are easier if you read the docs :). I would recommend you to [do the blog tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html) (not read, *do*) before continuing with the inherited project.

Answer (score 3):

When requesting models for which no concrete model class exists (or cannot be found for whatever reason), dynamic model objects will be generated from the `AppModel` class.

From the CakePHP Cookbook:

> CakePHP will dynamically create a model object for you if it cannot find a corresponding file in `/app/Model`. This also means that if your model file isn’t named correctly (for instance, if it is named ingredient.php or `Ingredients.php` rather than `Ingredient.php`), CakePHP will use an instance of `AppModel` rather than your model file (which CakePHP assumes is missing). If you’re trying to use a method you’ve defined in your model, or a behavior attached to your model, and you’re getting SQL errors that are the name of the method you’re calling, it’s a sure sign that CakePHP can’t find your model and you need to check the file names, your application cache, or both.

**http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models.html#understanding-models**

Comment: Thanks ndm for your fast answer. I have read this already. But if you use this class Postcode, how is it related with the table postcodes ?

Comment: @Francois99 I don't know hat you mean by "_how is it related_", you need to be a little more specific. I you mean how CakePHP knows to use the table `postcodes` for the model `Postcode`, then the answer is "[**naming conventions**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions)", models are singular camel capsed table names, and vice versa tables are plural underscored model names.

Comment: thank you very much, I had not expected this, cakePHP is smart. Indeed Inflector::pluralize('Postcode') = Postcodes (and so postcodes because Postcodes does not exits)

Comment: @Francois99 Actually models use [**`Inflector::tableize()`**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/inflector.html#Inflector::tableize).

Comment: @ndm, AD7six, thanks, indeed Inflector::tableize('Postcode') = 'postcodes'

Answer (score 0):

By the sounds of it you need to create a class for your 'postcodes',

Read the following: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models.html

But it should look something like this:

```
// app/Model/Postcode.php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class PostCode extends AppModel {

    public $validate = array(
        // Validation
    );

   // Replace 'ModelName' with the name of the class where the code sites you mentioned above
    public $hasMany = array(
        'ModelName' => array(
            'className' => 'ModelName',
            'foreignKey' => 'postcode_id'
        )
    );
}
```